# Обособление оборотов "не кто иной, как"; он, а не кто другой

Tags: пунктуация

1) **У Розенталя:** Спереди Рейнский водопад **не что иное, как** невысокий водяной уступ.

А если предложение не заканчивается оборотом, то запятая ставится или нет (и почему)? В текстах оборот пишется по-разному, например:
**Не кто иной, как Стив Джобс** настаивал именно на таком темпе выпуска фильмов. В первые же дни Февральской революции **не кто иной, как один из великих князей** рода Романовых надел на рукав красную повязку и вышел на улицы Петербурга!

**Но:** Не кто иной, **как он**, повел за собой этих офицеров, втянул их в эту войну.

2) **У Пушкина:** "Рассказывали о нем чудеса; имя Дубровского было во всех устах, все были уверены, что он, **а не кто другой,** предводительствовал отважными злодеями". **На каком основании обособлен оборот, какую функцию выполняет союз А?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1). Запятая закрывает сравнение (сравнительный оборот).

Поэтому -

*Не кто иной, как Стив Джобс, настаивал именно на таком темпе выпуска фильмов. В первые же дни Февральской революции не кто иной, как один из великих князей рода Романовых, надел на рукав красную повязку и вышел на улицы Петербурга!*

2) Из [Культуры письменной речи](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.31) Валгиной:

> Союз **как** синонимичен союзу **а**, отчетливо выражающему
>   противительные отношения.

Но в примере из Пушкина иное. Союз просто один из противительных, а обособлен *вкусово*, как вставная конструкция.

Гугл-Книги приводят потрясающие результаты вкусовщины - знаки Пушкину расставляли после реформы-56:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В издании 1904 года эта запятая стоит, зато...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...зато другая редакторская вольность наличествует - см. и ср. второе предложение в абзаце:

> Вскоре другие вести дали другую пищу любопытству и толкам. В **
>   появились разбойники и распространили ужас по всем окрестностям.

Comment: Спасибо, Галина, за ответ.  1) Мне эта конструкция кажется похожей на противопоставление: не кто иной, как (а) для однородных членов, которые НЕ ДОЛЖНЫ ОБОСОБЛЯТЬСЯ. В текстах чаще встречается необособленный вариант,  а в учебниках  подобные примеры не рассматриваются. 2) Существуют два обособленных оборота с одинаковым значением, но разной грамматикой: Он вывесил ящик для жалоб и писем перед своим замком, потому что ведь он, А НЕ КТО ДРУГОЙ,  был отцом отечества. «Отца Петра!» – просили прихожане, настаивая на том, чтобы только он,  И НИКТО ДРУГОЙ,  проводил службы.

Comment: Союз И - присоединительный, оборот обособляется,  а вот союз А какой и нужно ли обособлять оборот?

Comment: Сибилла, извините за запоздалый отклик (была "бессмертная" жизнь в Коте Инди)! Я в теории совсем несильна, просто чувствую это обособленное *а не кто другой* как синоним к *и не кто другой*. Как присоединительную конструкцию.